# Excel- Extract Number from Cell

Tags: regex, excel, extract

I have multiple cells that I am attempting to extract a number from, and need help finding a regex alternative.

The cells range in the following formats:

```
asdfs. Seat#29 asfddsa 
asdfsa. Seat#5d 
asdfasN/A . Seat#22 as789fsd 
Seat#111 words33
```

The closest that I came to a solution is:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID([@DisplayName],FIND("#",[@DisplayName])+1,3)),"")
```

As you can see this will extract most of the numbers but for some it leaves a character at the end.

The only commonality is the # preceding the seat number.  I am trying to extract only the seat number, no other numbers.

I cannot use VBA, this must be done using formulas.  I have figured this out once before but stupidly pasted over the formulas with a values only paste.

This can be done utilizing a flash fill, but I was hoping for a more stable formula.

Comment: If an array formula is viable, here is a sample https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1622-excel-extract-number-from-string.html

Comment: RegEx in Excel only works through vba.  You want to parse the data with a formula.  RegEx also works in Google Sheets if you want to switch.

Comment: You say the numbers you want are always preceded by a `#`. Are they always followed by a space or the end of the string?

Comment: In the case of `Seat#5d` do you want `5` or `5d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the numbers then use:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND("#",A1)+1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(1:5)/(ISERROR(--MID(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("#",A1),""),ROW(1:5),1))),1)-1)
```

[image]

If you want the letter also then:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("#",A1)+1,FIND(" ",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("#",A1),""))-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Scott,

Your first solution worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the letter following the seat number, you can use

```
.*#(\d+)
```

Edit for clarity: Excel does not have regex functions built in. You will either have to use a UDF (I can help with that if you'd like) or use a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without VBA to extract all numbers inside the strings.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fk6VFznD3i8s6scADy_vXCEj-1zQpBPW

Sheet #3

Comment: The OP does not want all numbers just the ones following the `#`

Comment: But that's what it does

Comment: 1. The original link went somewhere else. 2. Link only answers are frowned upon here.  answer the question in verbiage form, with the formulas as text in the answer and a photo to back it up.

Comment: that's a nicer way to do it, Scott :)

Comment: I'm not much into beautyness ... I'm more concerned with solving the problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with beauty it has to do with what is deemed an acceptable answer. Remember this is for not only this questioner but those who come in the future and links may or may not be there in the future.

Comment: Well, if I had this problem and someone posted a solution in my format, I would take it. But, yours is prettier ... lol